# How to find or count the duplicate in multidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am creating a **2d** `(3 * 3)` array in c# which has to count or find the *duplicate* value

```
int[,] arr = new int[3, 3] {
   {1, 2, 6},
   {4, 1, 5},
   {6, 1, 8}
};
```

I expected the output has `1` and `6` are the *duplicate values*

For beginners only with `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `HashSet<int>`, e.g.

```
   int[,] arr = new int[3, 3] {
      {1, 2, 6 }, 
      {4, 1, 5 }, 
      {6, 1, 8 }
   };

   HashSet<int> unique = new HashSet<int>();

   foreach (var item in arr)
     if (!unique.Add(item))
       Console.WriteLine(item);  // Not unique, print it out
```

**Outcome:**

```
  1
  6
  1
```

If we want to print each duplicate *once*, we can add another `HashSet<int>`:

```
   HashSet<int> unique = new HashSet<int>();
   HashSet<int> duplicates = new HashSet<int>();

   foreach (var item in arr)
     if (!unique.Add(item))
       duplicates.Add(item);  

   foreach (var item in duplicates)
     Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Finally, if you want to count duplicate occurences we can change `HashSet<int> duplicates` into `Dictionary<int, int> duplicates`:

```
   HashSet<int> unique = new HashSet<int>();

   Dictionary<int, int> duplicates = new Dictionary<int, int>();

   foreach (var item in arr)
     if (!unique.Add(item)) 
       if (duplicates.TryGetValue(item, out int count))
         duplicates[item] = count + 1;
       else
         duplicates[item] = 2; 

   foreach (var item in duplicates)
     Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} appears {item.Value} times");
```

**Edit:** you can change `foreach` loop into *nested* `for` ones, e.g:

All duplicates

```
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); ++j)
       if (!unique.Add(arr[i, j]))
         Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j]);
```

Distinct duplicates

```
   HashSet<int> duplicates = new HashSet<int>();

   for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); ++j)
       if (!unique.Add(arr[i, j]))
         if (duplicates.Add(arr[i, j]))   // print distinct duplicate only
           Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to do this with only for loop

Comment: @Arun Kumar: you can turn `foreach` loop into *nested* `for` ones (see my edit)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps like this:

```
var arr = new int[3, 3]{{1,2,6}, {4,1,5}, {6,1,8}};
var duplicates = arr
    .Cast<int>()
    .GroupBy(n => n)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

`.Cast<int>()` makes the array usable for LINQ, `.GroupBy(n => n)` groups numbers by their value, `.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` counts the number of items in the group, `.Select(g => g.Key)` returns only the group keys - the original values.

Do `.Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Count())` to return the counts of each, or just operate on the groups as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but you could also store your counts in a dictionary, then print the keys that have a count of more than 1:

```
var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var number = arr[i, j];
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(number))
        {
            counts[number] = 0;
        }
        counts[number] += 1;
    }
}

foreach (var pair in counts)
{
    if (pair.Value > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    }
}

// 1
// 6
```